# Hugo markdown metadata

Tags: yaml, markdown, metadata, hugo, toml

I want to show metadata from the markdown file on the webpage so I'm trying to access it using the variable names (e.g. {{ .Author}} ).

This works fine with the .Title and .Content variables, but does not work with the others! It seems like I'm missing an important detail on how to use these. With the .Author variable the output on the page is { map[]}.

Thanks in advance

**Markdown file:**

```
---
title: ABC
author: "Foo Bar"
position: Manager
---


The actual content ...
```

**Webpage:**

```
{{ range where .Data.Pages "Type" "type"}}
<section>
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ .Title }}<br>
            {{ .Content }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ .Author }}<br>
            {{ .Position }}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need to access the non-standard parameters via the .Params variable.

See https://gohugo.io/variables/page/ for the relevant information.

```
{{ range where .Data.Pages "Type" "type"}}
<section>
<div>
    <div>
        {{ .Title }}<br>
        {{ .Content }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ .Params.author }}<br>
        {{ .Params.position }}
    </div>
</div>
</section>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a menu, it seems `.Params.author` fails. So this should work:

Let’s say you have in your `.md` file the metadata:

```
author: Bob Dole
menu: "guest"
```

Your menu can access the author if you use `{{ with .Page }}` and `{{ .Params.author }}`

```
{{ range .Site.Menus.guest }}
  <div>
    {{ with .Page }}
      {{ .Name }} - {{ .Params.author}}
    {{ end }}
  </div>
{{ end }}
```